# Printing secret value in Databricks

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-spark, pyspark, databricks, azure-databricks

Even though secrets are for masking confidential information, I need to see the value of the secret for using it outside Databricks.
When I simply print the secret it shows [REDACTED].

```
print(dbutils.secrets.get(scope="myScope", key="myKey"))

Out:
[REDACTED]
```

How can I print the secret value?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Databricks redacts secret values that are read using `dbutils.secrets.get()`. When displayed in notebook cell output, the secret values are replaced with `[REDACTED]`.

Although it is not recommended, there is a workaround to see actual value with a simple `for loop` trick. So, you will get the value separated by spaces.

```
value = dbutils.secrets.get(scope="myScope", key="myKey")

for char in value:
    print(char, end=" ")

Out:
y o u r _ v a l u e
```

Comment: This will print out [REDACTED] instead of the value, no? This should print the value of the secret, with spaces: `' '.join([x for x in dbutils.secrets.get(scope="myScope", key="myKey")])`

Comment: I forgot to add space to the end argument. (end=" "). It should work fine.

Comment: this is a useful hack especially if you're debugging and maybe want to make sure databricks is using the correct keys

Answer (score 5):

You could get the printed value without spaces, so it is easier to read using the zero width space:

```
value = dbutils.secrets.get(scope="myScope", key="myKey")

for char in value:
    print(char, end='\u200B')

Out:
your_value
```

Notice this is adding a character that would be included if you print or copy the text like

```
y\u200b\u200bo\u200bu\u200br\u200b_\u200bv\u200ba\u200bl\u200bu\u200be\u200b
```

Which could be worse than better. Still, if you want to read the value, it's easier to the eye with the zero width space

Comment: Thanks, easier to read and copy paste!
One row version -> print('\u200B'.join([x for x in dbutils.secrets.get(scope="myScope",key="myKey")]))

Answer (score 0):

An other approach is to extract the secret as byte representation and display it in outside of Databricks.
First on Databricks:

```py
import base64

secret_str = dbutils.secrets.get(scope="your_scope", key="your_key")

secret_bytes = secret_str.encode('utf-8')

encoded_secret = base64.b64encode(secret_bytes)

print(encoded_secret)
```

copy the b64 secret. Then on your machine:

```py
import base64

encoded_secret = "here the encoded secret"
decoded_secret = base64.b64decode(encoded_secret).decode('utf-8')

print(decoded_secret)
```

Why on your machine ? Databricks intercepts secrets and replace it by REDACTED. It will not happen on a non Databricks environment.